# Cannot implicity convert type int to string?

Tags: c#

Estou aqui copiando um tutorial e está dando um erro que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Erro:

> cannot implicity convert type int to string

Código:

```
    label_nome.Text = "Funcionario" + num_funcionario;
    count_idade.Value = 18;
}
private void cmd_contratar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FUNCIONARIOS.Add(new cl_funcionario() { 
        nome = label_nome.Text, 
        idade = (int)count_idade.Value // Erro 
    });
    num_funcionario++;
}
```

Comment: Eu diria que `num_funcionario` é um `int` e você está tentando concatená-lo com uma *String*. Não seria o caso de fazer `num_funcionario.ToString()`?

Comment: Precisamos que você disponibilize a classe e adeque o texto como fiz na edição, esse `cast` é inválido, mas, para onde ele está indo eu também não sei o que recebe, fica tudo complicado se não postar os itens relacionados. Como foi dito um `ToString()` pode resolver, mas, se o problema for maior e ai não tem como saber.

Comment: é isso mesmo obrigado

Comment: Cuidado para não fazer conversões desnecessárias, cuidado que eu acho que está indo pelo caminho errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que você esta tentando concatenar um int com uma String

```
label_nome.Text = "Funcionario" + num_funcionario.ToString();
```

isso deve resolver

Comment: obrigado. resolvido